# Java string find and replace with different value each time for a key

Tags: java

I am facing trouble to replace some value inside a string.

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"djdhsja","BizProcessNm":"value5",.........}
```

I have to replace the value of key4 to "something". As shown below

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"something","BizProcessNm":"value5",.........}
```

The problem is I don't know the exact value inside the value of key4. In this case, "djdhsja" is the value. It will be random.

I thought of getting the position of key4 in the string and then based on the string position, replace the content after first " till it ends with "something". But this may be a little complicated as i have to do this for so many strings inside a for loop(The loop was written by someone else, I am just modifying it).

Is there any regex kind of find and replace like sed in linux.

edit: The position of key4 is random

Comment: why don't use JSON parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is no whitespace between key, colon and value and also no quotation mark inside the current value of `key4` you can use the following line of code to replace the value:

```
s.replaceFirst("(?<=\\\"key4\\\":\\\")(.*?)(?=\\\")", "new value");
```

The regex is using positive look-behind and look-ahead so that only the text inside the quotation marks of the value is replaced.

While this may be applicable for a one-time action I'd rather suggest using a JSON-parser as suggested in the comments and Marcell's answer.

Comment: I am actually looking for a solution like this. Thanks for the help. Actually, i have to iterate over some 1000's of records which they are iterating over a loop, creating a JSON object and then modifying it may lead to more time complexity for each record. Your solution fulfilled the need

Comment: Hi, how do i update existing value. for ex., append some string to existing string?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you have JSON-like key-value pairs.
In that case I would convert the json into a java object. There are some libraries written for that (ex. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Than you can simply get and set the fields of that object.

If it is a map, or something similar, you can still get the value of "key4" by the key "key4".

And finally, if you have something totally else, like a string with that content, you can use something like:

```
yourString.split(",")[3].split(":")[1];
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add that the position of key4 is random so using the array index will create a problem for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your String into JSon Object and then convert that json into Map and perform your tasks,

```
    Map map;
    map = (Map) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObj, Map.class);
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

Here `jsonObj` is json object which is get cretaed from your String value.

and on Conditional check for key, update the value of the particular key.